# Getting through all entries in JS by queryselector

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get some informations from the page.
If there is one entry I can do that by

```
var z = document.querySelector('div.class').innerText;
```

and then get it by `+z` somewhere where I need the value.

But if there are more entries it will get only first.
I'm trying to do sth like that to get them all:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('div.class');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerText;
}
```

But definitely something's wrong with this code. I'm not really familiar with JS, could you help me how to get all entries?

Comment: You can only have one id in a document, use a class instead

Comment: id values have to be *unique* in the document.

Comment: Oh, actually I'm using classes, just wanted to show easily the #example

Comment: You appear to be getting them all, and just not doing anything with them. Try providing an [mcve] and telling us what the difference between the expected and actual result is.

Comment: I think there's nothing more to show. I have somewhere in code the divs with class called "class" and I want to get the text from it. It works with queryselector, but this gets only first div. I want to get all of them.

Comment: What is `x[i].innerText;` supposed to do? It gets the innerText of the element and then does nothing with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using getElementsByClassName('class').
The script would be sort of:

```
let list = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    console.log(list[i].innerText);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/esjcaqwb/

Answer (score 0):

With your actual code you are not doing anything in the loop, the statement `x[i].innerText;` does nothing.

If you want to get these elements contents in an `array` you can use:

```
var results = Array.from(x).forEach(function(el){
   return el.innerText;
});
```

Comment: No, no, I've edited my post. It was only an example. In really it's a class, not ID.

Comment: Because I want to get those values later in `window.open('http://link.com/calculate?something='+x ,'_blank', "width=750, height=850"); `
It works like this with queryselector, but not with second code based on queryselectorall
Do you have ideas how to make it right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, heres a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/t7twp5gh/) that might be useful.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.example');
var r = document.querySelectorAll('.result')

var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    r.innerText += x[i].innerText;
}
```

What was going wrong with your code? In the example you provided, you're getting the value but not doing anything with it.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken

Comment: Thanks for your example, but I want to get those values later in `window.open('http://link.com/calculate?something='+x ,'_blank', "width=750, height=850");` It works like this with queryselector, but not with second code based on queryselectorall. Do you have ideas how to make it right?

Comment: @jampjamp Create a list `theValues = []` and add the values to it with `theValues.push(x[i].innerText)`. Then use a for-loop to iter over `theValues`